# Video classification with AWS Lambda websocket and Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to do webcam video classification with AWS Sagemaker. I currently have a proof-of-concept pipeline that works, which looks like:

1. Front-end gets frame of video
2. Sends in websocket to AWS API Gateway
3. Uses a Lambda proxy to send the image to Sagemaker, which classifies the image and returns a prediction

This works for images. I'm trying to move to multiple frames - i.e. video. AWS has a limit of 32kb in each websocket message, so I can't concatenate frames, each of which is ~30kb. So I have to send each frame separately. What is the simplest way to insert some concept of "connected messages" into this pipeline? Do I have to use a database (e.g. Dynamo DB) or is there any concept of preserving information across websocket messages / Lambda function calls?